# Model Data not passing to View in Asp Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an action method which returns a partial view

```
public PartialViewResult GemByMonth(int id,string btn)
{
    if (btn == "bymnthbtn1")
    {
     var birthgembymonth1 = dbcontext.GemStoneByMonths.Where(p => p.GemStoneByMonthId == id).Select(q => new { q.GemEng, q.GemImage });
        return PartialView("_BirthGemByMonthEng", birthgembymonth1);
    }

    return PartialView();
}
```

My Partial View is

```
@model Astrology.Models.GemStoneByMonth

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="height: 100%;margin-top: 12%;font-size: 2em"> @Model.GemEng</div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><img style="height: 7em; margin-left: 7em; margin-top: 3em" src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.GemImage)" /></div>
</div>
```

My model class

```
  public class GemStoneByMonth
    {

        public int GemStoneByMonthId { get; set; }
        public string EnglishZodiac { get; set; }
        public string MalayalamZodiac { get; set; }
        public string SanskritZodiac { get; set; }
        public string GemEng { get; set; }
        public string GemMal { get; set; }
        public byte[] GemImage { get; set; }
    }
```

I have 2 buttons. so to distinguish from which button the click event occurs i added values to my button which is accessed via string 'btn' variable.

But the model data i passed to the partial view is not passing to my partial view. can someone help me with it?

Comment: Try adding a .Single() to the end of your query.  Right now you are passing an IQueryable to the view and not a materialized object.

Comment: Can you please share your partial view code?

Comment: I have updated the code. please check,

Comment: use this one: var birthgembymonth1 = dbcontext.GemStoneByMonths.FirstOrDefault(p => p.GemStoneByMonthId == id);

Comment: Actually you are selecting only `image` not the full model. So you will have to either bind Image model or use the above piece of code.

Comment: Please share the definition of `GemStoneByMonth` object. Because What you put there is only the query, you need to execute it with `.toList()`, `.First()` etc.

Comment: i only want to pass some table value to view. not all. so i can get appropriate  value from each button click. each button click should fetch only some data,

Comment: i have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq query is lazy loading by default, until you explicitly call `ToList()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `First()` or so on.

I believe you want to use `FirstOrDefault()`, if you want to get the single value. In addition, you need to pass the model as `GemStoneByMonth` instead of anonymous type.

```
public PartialViewResult GemByMonth(int id, string btn)
{
    if (btn == "bymnthbtn1")
    {
        var entity = dbcontext.GemStoneByMonths
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.GemStoneByMonthId == id);

        var birthgembymonth1 = new GemStoneByMonth
        {
            GemEng = entity.GemEng,
            GemImage = entity.GemImage
        };    
        return PartialView("_BirthGemByMonthEng", birthgembymonth1);
    }
    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: Got exception. Additional information: The entity or complex type 'Astrology.AstroDatabase.GemStoneByMonth' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: I updated the answer. Could you try retrieving all columns of a single record of GemStoneByMonths for now, and see it solves the problem?

Comment: Yes it gets the value and updated partialview. But i only want to pass sone column values and thats why i used btn name to distinguish.

Comment: can i type an if statement in my view? does it have any negetive impact like logic in view? i think i need a view model.

Comment: You could add if statement inside View, unless you have a very complex business logic. We normally place complex logic inside Action method, so that we can unit test the logic.

Comment: Actually i need 2 data in my partialview. so if user is selecting english i want english data. if other language i want curresponding translated data. Inshort i want 2 properties which is common. so i think it is better to create a view model with common properties and assign data to those properties according to the if statement. so i can use it in view generally. Well your answer opened my eyes to this solution. :D

Answer (score 1):

Use viewdata then as you are selecting some values from the whole model. You can't bind whole model where you are only selecting few properties.

```
var birthgembymonth1 = dbcontext.GemStoneByMonths.FirstOrDefault(p => p.GemStoneByMonthId == id);
ViewBag.GemEng = birthgembymonth1.GemEng;
ViewBag.GemImage = birthgembymonth1.GemImage;
```

Then in razor view get those values using:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="height: 100%;margin-top: 12%;font-size: 2em"> @ViewBag.GemEng</div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><img style="height: 7em; margin-left: 7em; margin-top: 3em" src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(ViewBag.GemImage)" /></div>
</div>
```

When you use `select` then c# creates new dynamic object so binding `GemStoneByMonth` in the model won't work.

Comment: I know it can be solved by using viewbag or viewdata. Im thinking using viewbags is not a good coding standard and can slow down. so i was searching for passing data via model. Is there any problem if i use viewbag?

Comment: Yes, it's little bit slower than the model. But in case you want to transfer only 2 values then creating model is not necessary i guess :)